# How to execute a Python script using the Python DLL?

Tags: python, dll

I have a Python DLL already shipped and installed on the end user (guaranteed, and with a known version number).

How can I use this DLL to execute some Python scripts without shipping the Python interpreter (again)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to [embed Python](http://docs.python.org/extending/embedding.html) in another application, and use [`PyRun_AnyFile*()`](http://docs.python.org/c-api/veryhigh.html#PyRun_AnyFile) to run it.